# Kotlin Convert Genertic Class to Map

Tags: kotlin, serialization, jackson, inline

there is a `A Data Class`

```
data class A(val x: String?, val y: Int?)
```

and I have to one two and if there're null value in `one` then replace it `two`'s property value but if not null then remain `one`'s value

```
val one = A(null, 3) 
val two = A("11", 4)

A("11", 3)
```

The idea I came up with is convert two A object to Map and merge two Map
and then deserialize merged Map to A

My question is

1. is there any best idea merge two object?(My Situation)
2. How to convert Generic Class To Map

```
inline fun <reified T> toJsonObject(value: T): Map<String, Any> =
        objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value), Map::class.java)
```

this does not working please help me..

Comment: Please remove question 2 and post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible only with reflection:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMembers
   
inline fun <reified T> T.takeValuesIfNullFrom(item: T): T {
  if(this!!::class != item!!::class) return this
  val constructor = T::class.constructors.first()
  val parameterNames = constructor.parameters.map { parameter -> parameter.name }
  val arguments = T::class.declaredMembers
    .filter { it.name in parameterNames }
    .map { it.call(if (it.call(this) == null) item else this) }
  return constructor.call(*arguments.toTypedArray())
}
```

Test:

```
data class A(val x: String?, val y: Int?)

val one = A(null, 3)
val two = A("11", 4)

data class B(val x: String?, val y: Int?, val z: Float?)

val three = B(null, 5, null)
val four = B("22", 6, 123.456f)

val resultA = one.takeValuesIfNullFrom(two)
println(resultA)

val resultB = three.takeValuesIfNullFrom(four)
println(resultB)
```

Output:

```
A(x=11, y=3)
B(x=22, y=5, z=123.456)
```

Comment: thanks for answerWhat I want to do is apply it generic data calsses

Comment: I made the necessary changes.

Comment: really thanks...

Comment: may I ask one more thing?


how can I change takeValuesIfNullFrom if there is data class In A

for example)
data class B(val x: String?) // data class A(val x: String?, val y:B?)

Comment: If there is data class in A then takeValuesIfNullFrom does not work any more

data class B(val x: String?)

data class A(val x: String?, val y: B?)

Comment: It does: _val b1 = B("b"); val a1 = A(null, null); val a2 = A("a2", b1); val result = a1.takeValuesIfNullFrom(a2)_

Comment: now I get it.. why my case fails..
In case both property have null value. then it does not work

Comment: It works, but you have to do it in two steps. You first have to get a valid B instance, and then do A with the valid B.

Comment: yes it works.. found some bugs in my code..

Comment: really thanks!!!!! :)

Comment: is it possible to change takeValuesIfNullFrom that support nested object
give me some hint ...